# Deleting duplicates in SQL in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that consists of the columns id(key), symbol, direction, range, price, percent.  I would like to delete the data where the symbol, direction, price, and percent are the same that has the lowest range. How would I accomplish this?

I have been trying to alter this statement: `DELETE
FROM aw
WHERE id not in (select min(id) from aw group by symbol, direction, price, percent);` to get something to work.

Comment: I'm unclear about your first paragraph.  Does that mean you want to keep only one row for each combination of symbol, direction, price, and percent ... and that row should be the first with the lowest range value for that combination of fields?

Comment: @HansUp that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample data for the *aw* table.  Based on your description, I think you want to discard the rows with `ID` values of 2, 3, and 5.

```sql
ID symbol direction range price percent
1  a      x            15    10       5
2  a      x            20    10       5
3  b      y            40    50       5
4  b      y            10    50       5
5  a      x            15    10       5
```

Determine the minimum range value for each combination of `symbol`, `direction`, `price`, and `percent`.

**qryMinRanges**:

```sql
SELECT
    aw.symbol,
    aw.direction,
    aw.price,
    aw.[percent],
    Min(aw.range) AS MinOfrange
FROM aw
GROUP BY
    aw.symbol,
    aw.direction,
    aw.price,
    aw.[percent];
```

... which gives this result set:

```sql
symbol direction price percent MinOfrange
a      x            10       5         15
b      y            50       5         10
```

Determine the minimum `ID` for each of those minimum ranges.

**qryMinID_forMinRanges**:

```sql
SELECT
    q.symbol,
    q.direction,
    q.price,
    q.[percent],
    q.MinOfrange,
    Min(aw.ID) AS MinOfID
FROM
    qryMinRanges AS q
    INNER JOIN aw
    ON
        (q.MinOfrange = aw.range)
        AND (q.[percent] = aw.[percent])
        AND (q.price = aw.price)
        AND (q.direction = aw.direction)
        AND (q.symbol = aw.symbol)
GROUP BY
    q.symbol,
    q.direction,
    q.price,
    q.[percent],
    q.MinOfrange;
```

... which gives this result set:

```sql
symbol direction price percent MinOfrange MinOfID
a      x            10       5         15       1
b      y            50       5         10       4
```

So *qryMinID_forMinRanges* should represent the rows you want to keep.  Ultimately you will delete the rows from *aw* whose ID values are not included in *qryMinID_forMinRanges*.  But first try this `SELECT` query to confirm you're targeting the correct records for deletion.

```sql
SELECT
    aw.ID,
    aw.symbol,
    aw.direction,
    aw.range,
    aw.price,
    aw.[percent]
FROM aw
WHERE aw.ID Not In
    (SELECT MinOfID FROM qryMinID_forMinRanges);
```

... which gives me this result set:

```sql
ID symbol direction range price percent
 2 a      x            20    10       5
 3 b      y            40    50       5
 5 a      x            15    10       5
```

So, if that looks correct, change it to a DELETE query.

```sql
DELETE *
FROM aw
WHERE
    (((aw.ID) Not In
        (SELECT MinOfID FROM qryMinID_forMinRanges)));
```

The db engine doesn't require the `*` after DELETE.  But if you want to use the query designer's preview, you need to give it a field spec to display.

Please take precautions to safeguard your data in case I screwed up any details here.  Backups are good.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `exists` clause:

```
DELETE FROM aw 
WHERE 
    exists (
        select
            1
        from
            (select symbol, direction, price, percent, min(range) as minrange from aw
            group by symbol, direction, price, percent) aw2
        where
            aw2.symbol = aw.symbol
            and aw2.direction = aw.direction
            and aw2.price = aw.price
            and aw2.percent = aw.percent
            and aw2.minrange = aw.range
    )
```

Comment: but i need the min range, not min id

Comment: I would not just go ahead and run a `DELETE` query like this. Who knows what it might do if it has a bug; it might just delete everything.

Comment: @MikeNakis you are funny. In this case, you should test it before run it on production :)

Comment: @Eric it looks like it is having trouble finding aw.range